# Is there a way in Emacs to fill a paragraph containing some read-only characters?

Tags: emacs, markdown, readonly-attribute

In Emacs I am using [cm-mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/criticmarkup-emacs%60) with markdown buffers. cm-mode inserts a few read-only characters to indicate document changes. When I issue `fill-paragraph` the fill is aborted with the message `read-only Text`.

Is there a way to fill a paragraph containing a few read-only characters? (I.e. after the fill the read-only characters should be read-only  again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind or temporarily set `inhibit-read-only` to non-nil. `C-h v` tells us:

> `inhibit-read-only` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means disregard read-only status of buffers or characters.
>
> If the value is `t`, disregard `buffer-read-only` and all `read-only`
>   text properties.  If the value is a list, disregard `buffer-read-only`
>   and disregard a `read-only` text property if the property value
>   is a member of the list.

Comment: It works! Thanks. - I just defined `(defun disregard-read-only () (interactive) (setq inhibit-read-only t)), but is there a predefined function/package for this?

Comment: No command by default, that I know of. Just `M-: (setq inhibit-read-only t)`. But typically you want instead to *bind* it only in the context of some function, rather that setting it.

Comment: Great idea: I can have my own `my-fill-paragraph` that binds `inhibit-read-only` first! - Still very annoying that cm-mode forces me to do this...